# Django Returns 403 Forbidden for Email view

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a simple contact form in Django, but I'm stuck with a 403 Forbidden error. How can I pinpoint a 403 error with Django? The page I'm redirected to doesn't seem to explain anything:

> Reason given for failure:
>
> ```
> CSRF token missing or incorrect.
> ```

I'm following the guide from djangobook.com Chapter 7: Forms and I'm on **Making a Contact Form**

This is pretty much exactly what I have for my contact view:

```
def contact(request):
    errors = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('subject', ''):
            errors.append('Enter a subject.')
        if not request.POST.get('message', ''):
            errors.append('Enter a message.')
        if request.POST.get('email') and '@' not in request.POST['email']:
            errors.append('Enter a valid e-mail address.')
        if not errors:
            send_mail(
                request.POST['subject'],
                request.POST['message'],
                request.POST.get('email', 'cinicraftmatt@gmail.com'),
                ['cinicraftmatt@gmail.com'],
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    return render(request, 'contact_form.html',
        {'errors': errors})
```

How could someone pinpoint this problem and solve it with little explanation given?

Answer (score 0):

Most possibly you miss the `{% csrf_token %}` in your html template between the form tags.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the book barely mentions that you need to add smtp info to your settings.py file

Here's an example if you use gmail:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'YourGmail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password123'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'replyService@gmail.com'
DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = 'Optional@gmail.com'
```